# Using azure azurerm_resource_provider_registration with newly created subscription

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure

I am working on creating Azure landing zone and part of that is to enable/disable resource providers on the newly created subscriptions.

I have tried to used alias with a variable but i am getting error that i cant use variable in an alias so is there any way through which i can use this feature on multiple subscription

This is my code main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

#list of providers i want to register
locals {
  # List is compiled from here
  # https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers
  provider_list = [
    "Microsoft.Storage"
  ]
  provider_map = { for p in local.provider_list : p => p }
}

# Registering a default provider here and skipping registration 
# as i will do it later
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

# I am creating a subscription here with same alias as the name
# the subscription is being created under and EA enrollment but 
# any type of subscription will do
resource "azurerm_subscription" "feature_subscription" {
  billing_scope_id  = "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/xxx/enrollmentAccounts/xx"
  alias = var.temp_alias # "test-provider-registration"
  subscription_name = "test-provider-registration"
}

#this is what i have created to point out my azurerm_resource_provider_registration
#module i am using variable in alias which is failing
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = var.temp_alias
  subscription_id = azurerm_subscription.feature_subscription.id
  features {

  }
  skip_provider_registration = true
}


#module through which i am registering the resource providers
module "azurerm_resource_provider_registration-provider" {
  source = "../modules/azurerm_resource_provider_registration"
  providers =  {
    azurerm = azurerm.test-provider-registration
  }
  feature_list = local.provider_map 
}

#the module code is mentioned here
#resource "azurerm_resource_provider_registration" "provider" {
#  for_each =  var.feature_list
#  name     = each.value
#}
```

I am getting this error when i run it

> There are some problems with the configuration, described below.
>
> The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
> Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
> ╷
> Error: Variables not allowed
> │
> On main.tf line 25: Variables may not be used here.
> ╵
>
> ╷
> Error: Unsuitable value type
> │
> On main.tf line 25: Unsuitable value: value must be known

There is a workaround available like using this

```
resource "null_resource" "provider_registration" {
  for_each = local.provider_map
  
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az account set --subscription ${data.azurerm_subscription.subscription.subscription_id} && az provider register --namespace ${each.value}"
  }
}
```

but i want to use the state file for the resource registration if possible as i have more subscriptions in a loop

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Unsuitable value type | Unsuitable value: value must be known

***Need to check:***

1. This problem usually occurs with `module` sources or versions. When invoking a module, using variables instead of passing direct values for the source and some other arguments causes this error. `terraform init`doesn't take variable inputs with modules in backend state configuration.

**Note**: And also include required version for modules.

2. To make it work, use direct values for module block instead of accessing from other resources.
3. Pass provider explicitly to make it work as detailed in [terraform providers](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly).

```bash
 providers =  {
    azurerm = azurerm.test-provider-registration
    }
  feature_list = local.provider_map 
}
}
module "azurerm_resource_provider_registration-provider" {
  source ="../modules/azurerm_resource_provider_registration"
  version = <required version> //Use latest one
```

After checking the above conditions, I tried same in my environment and it was ***initialized successfully:***

[image]

Refer [aliasing](https://jeffbrown.tech/terraform-azure-multiple-subscriptions/) for the deployment in multiple subscriptions detailed by @Jeff Brown

Comment: So this works if i change this
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = var.temp_alias
  subscription_id = azurerm_subscription.feature_subscription.id
  features {

  }
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

to this 

provider "azurerm" {
  alias = var.temp_alias
  subscription_id = azurerm_subscription.feature_subscription.id
  features {

  }
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

The alias works if the value is directly there and that is where i am having challenge as i will get the name from new subscription variable. 
module it works fine if i just change that line

Comment: Yes as described in the above answer.

Comment: The main problem here is actully to use a provider with an alias of a subscription which we just created and in a landing zone we create quite a few subscription and we need to register certain modules in each subscription. I can even skip the module

Comment: Did you declare a variable for `var.temp_alias` in `variable.tf` file?